# Creating an In-Bot Language Selection Menu for a Multilingual Dialogflow Agent

Tags: dialogflow-es, dialogflow-cx

I need to create a language selection menu in a multilingual Dialogflow CX agent. The menu should be within the bot itself, and once the language is selected, the bot should use it. I can't find a way to make it work without sending the language from outside Dialogflow. Any ideas? Ty.

I've created the menu, but I can't get it to change languages.